# Slow performance in agent based model python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, oop, game-theory

I originally posted this on code-review (hence the lengthy code) but failed to get an answer.

My model is based on this game https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimatum_game . I won't go into the intuition behind it but generally speaking it functions as follows:

1. The game consists of a n x n lattice on which an agent is placed at each node.
2. During each time step, each player on each node plays against a random neighbour by playing a particular strategy.
3. Each of their strategies (a value between 1-9) has a propensity attached to it (which is randomly assigned and is just some number). The propensity then in turn determines the probability of playing that strategy. The probability is calculated as the propensity of that strategy over the sum of the propensities of all strategies.
4. If a game results in a positive payoff, then the payoffs from that game get added to the propensities for those strategies.
5. These propensities then determine the probabilities for their strategies in the next time step, and so on.
6. The simulation ends after time step N is reached.

For games with large lattices and large time steps, my code runs really really slowly. I ran cProfiler to check where the bottleneck(s) are, and as I suspected the `update_probabilities`and `play_rounds` functions seem to be taking up a lot time. I want to be able to run the game with gridsize of about 40x40 for about 100000+ time steps, but right now that is not happening.

So what would be a more efficient way to calculate and update the probabilities/propensities of each player in the grid? I've considered implementing NumPy arrays but I am not sure if it would be worth the hassle here?

```py
import numpy as np
import random
from random import randint
from numpy.random import choice
from numpy.random import multinomial
import cProfile

mew = 0.001 
error = 0.05

def create_grid(row, col):
    return [[0 for j in range(col)] for i in range(row)]

def create_random_propensities():
    propensities = {}
    pre_propensities = [random.uniform(0, 1) for i in range(9)]
    a = np.sum(pre_propensities)
    for i in range(1, 10):
        propensities[i] = (pre_propensities[i - 1]/a) * 10 # normalize sum of propensities to 10
    return propensities

class Proposer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.propensities = create_random_propensities()
        self.probabilites = []
        self.demand = 0 # the amount the proposer demands for themselves

    def pick_strat(self, n_trials): # gets strategy, an integer in the interval [1, 9]
        results = multinomial(n_trials, self.probabilites)
        i, = np.where(results == max(results))
        if len(i) > 1:
            return choice(i) + 1
        else:
            return i[0] + 1

    def calculate_probability(self, dict_data, index, total_sum): # calculates probability for particular strat, taking propensity
        return dict_data[index]/total_sum                           # of that strat as input

    def calculate_sum(self, dict_data):
        return sum(dict_data.values())

    def initialize(self):
        init_sum = self.calculate_sum(self.propensities)
        for strategy in range(1, 10):
            self.probabilites.append(self.calculate_probability(self.propensities, strategy, init_sum)) 
        self.demand = self.pick_strat(1)

    def update_strategy(self):
        self.demand = self.pick_strat(1)

    def update_probablities(self):
        for i in range(9):
            self.propensities[1 + i] *= 1 - mew 
        pensity_sum = self.calculate_sum(self.propensities)
        for i in range(9):
            self.probabilites[i] = self.calculate_probability(self.propensities, 1 + i, pensity_sum)

    def update(self):
        self.update_probablities()
        self.update_strategy()

class Responder: # methods same as proposer class, can skip-over
    def __init__(self):
        self.propensities = create_random_propensities()
        self.probabilites = []
        self.max_thresh = 0 # the maximum demand they are willing to accept 

    def pick_strat(self, n_trials):
        results = multinomial(n_trials, self.probabilites)
        i, = np.where(results == max(results))
        if len(i) > 1:
            return choice(i) + 1
        else:
            return i[0] + 1

    def calculate_probability(self, dict_data, index, total_sum):
        return dict_data[index]/total_sum

    def calculate_sum(self, dict_data):
        return sum(dict_data.values())

    def initialize(self):
        init_sum = self.calculate_sum(self.propensities)
        for strategy in range(1, 10):
            self.probabilites.append(self.calculate_probability(self.propensities, strategy, init_sum)) 
        self.max_thresh = self.pick_strat(1)

    def update_strategy(self):
        self.max_thresh = self.pick_strat(1)

    def update_probablities(self):
        for i in range(9):
            self.propensities[1 + i] *= 1 - mew # stops sum of propensites from growing without bound
        pensity_sum = self.calculate_sum(self.propensities)
        for i in range(9):
            self.probabilites[i] = self.calculate_probability(self.propensities, 1 + i, pensity_sum)

    def update(self):
        self.update_probablities()
        self.update_strategy()

class Agent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prop_side = Proposer()
        self.resp_side = Responder()
        self.prop_side.initialize()
        self.resp_side.initialize()

    def update_all(self):
        self.prop_side.update()
        self.resp_side.update()

class Grid:
    def __init__(self, rowsize, colsize):
        self.rowsize = rowsize
        self.colsize = colsize

    def make_lattice(self):
        return [[Agent() for j in range(self.colsize)] for i in range(self.rowsize)]

    @staticmethod
    def von_neumann_neighbourhood(array, row, col, wrapped=True): # gets up, bottom, left, right neighbours of some node
        neighbours = set([])

        if row + 1 <= len(array) - 1:
            neighbours.add(array[row + 1][col])

        if row - 1 >= 0:
            neighbours.add(array[row - 1][col])

        if col + 1 <= len(array[0]) - 1:
            neighbours.add(array[row][col + 1])

        if col - 1 >= 0:    
            neighbours.add(array[row][col - 1])
        #if wrapped is on, conditions for out of bound points
        if row - 1 < 0 and wrapped == True:
            neighbours.add(array[-1][col])

        if col - 1 < 0 and wrapped == True:
            neighbours.add(array[row][-1])

        if row + 1 > len(array) - 1 and wrapped == True:
            neighbours.add(array[0][col])

        if col + 1 > len(array[0]) - 1 and wrapped == True:
            neighbours.add(array[row][0])
        return neighbours

def get_error_term(pay, strategy):
    index_strat_2, index_strat_8 = 2, 8
    if strategy == 1:
        return (1 - (error/2)) * pay, error/2 * pay, index_strat_2
    if strategy == 9:
        return (1 - (error/2)) * pay, error/2 * pay, index_strat_8
    else:
        return (1 - error) * pay, error/2 * pay, 0

class Games:
    def __init__(self, n_rows, n_cols, n_rounds):
        self.rounds = n_rounds
        self.rows = n_rows
        self.cols = n_cols
        self.lattice = Grid(self.rows, self.cols).make_lattice()
        self.lookup_table = np.full((self.rows, self.cols), False, dtype=bool)  # if player on grid has updated their strat, set to True 

    def reset_look_tab(self):
        self.lookup_table = np.full((self.rows, self.cols), False, dtype=bool)

    def run_game(self):
        n = 0
        while n < self.rounds:
            for r in range(self.rows):
                for c in range(self.cols):
                    if n != 0:
                        self.lattice[r][c].update_all() 
                        self.lookup_table[r][c] = True
                    self.play_rounds(self.lattice, r, c)
            self.reset_look_tab()
            n += 1

    def play_rounds(self, grid, row, col):  
        neighbours = Grid.von_neumann_neighbourhood(grid, row, col)
        neighbour = random.sample(neighbours, 1).pop() 
        neighbour_index = [(ix, iy) for ix, row in enumerate(self.lattice) for iy, i in enumerate(row) if i == neighbour]
        if self.lookup_table[neighbour_index[0][0]][neighbour_index[0][1]] == False: # see if neighbour has already updated their strat
            neighbour.update_all()                                                      
        player = grid[row][col]
        coin_toss = randint(0, 1) # which player acts as proposer or responder in game
        if coin_toss == 1:
            if player.prop_side.demand <= neighbour.resp_side.max_thresh: # postive payoff
                payoff, adjacent_payoff, index = get_error_term(player.prop_side.demand, player.prop_side.demand)
                if player.prop_side.demand == 1 or player.prop_side.demand == 9: # extreme strategies get bonus payoffs
                    player.prop_side.propensities[player.prop_side.demand] += payoff
                    player.prop_side.propensities[index] += adjacent_payoff
                else:
                    player.prop_side.propensities[player.prop_side.demand] += payoff
                    player.prop_side.propensities[player.prop_side.demand - 1] += adjacent_payoff
                    player.prop_side.propensities[player.prop_side.demand + 1] += adjacent_payoff
            else:
                return 0 # if demand > max thresh -> both get zero

        if coin_toss != 1:
            if neighbour.prop_side.demand <= player.resp_side.max_thresh:
                payoff, adjacent_payoff, index = get_error_term(10 - neighbour.prop_side.demand, player.resp_side.max_thresh)
                if player.resp_side.max_thresh == 1 or player.resp_side.max_thresh == 9:
                    player.resp_side.propensities[player.resp_side.max_thresh] += payoff
                    player.resp_side.propensities[index] += adjacent_payoff
                else:
                    player.resp_side.propensities[player.resp_side.max_thresh] += payoff
                    player.resp_side.propensities[player.resp_side.max_thresh - 1] += adjacent_payoff
                    player.resp_side.propensities[player.resp_side.max_thresh + 1] += adjacent_payoff
            else:
                return 0

#pr = cProfile.Profile()
#pr.enable()

my_game = Games(10, 10, 2000) # (rowsize, colsize, n_steps)
my_game.run_game()

#pr.disable()
#pr.print_stats(sort='time')
```

(For those who might be wondering, the `get_error_term` just returns the propensities for strategies that are next to strategies that receive a positive payoff, for example if the strategy 8 works, then 7 and 9's propensities also get adjusted upwards and this is calculated by said function. And the first `for` loop inside `update_probabilities` just makes sure that the sum of propensities don't grow without bound).

Comment: Regarding the performance of your code, you should probably offer timing measures that point towards the slow parts, and indicate your expectations in terms of speed. You should also probably try using `numpy`; asking us "if it is worth the hassle" is a bit vain: try it, and find out, and if you face difficulties, ask us for help. Other avenues to explore are `pypy`, or `numba` JIT.

Comment: You have now a response on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/222974/agent-based-model-in-python)